# Swift Reverse Geocoding using the Data

Tags: swift, variables, geocode

I am successfully getting the current address details based on my location. It printlns perfectly. What is throwing me is how I extract the data from this call. I have tried passing, say the ZIP/Postcode, as local and even global variables but with no joy. The data only seems to exist within this call. How can I use it elsewhere?

```
// Get Address Information
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let newLocation = CLLocation(latitude: valueLatitude, longitude: valueLongitude)
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if error != nil {
            println("Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let placemark   = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            let addressDictionary = placemark.addressDictionary
            let address     = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressStreetKey] as! NSString
            let city        = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressCityKey] as! NSString
            let state       = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressStateKey] as! NSString
            let postcode    = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressZIPKey] as! NSString
            let country     = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressCountryKey] as! NSString

            println("\(address) \(city) \(state) \(postcode) \(country)") }
    })
```

Comment: Where is this called ?

Comment: It's within an IBAction. When the user presses the Save button a load of location data is saved. It executes this strip of code about halfway through.

Comment: Weird issue, you say if you assign your placemark object to a global var it doesn't work ?

Comment: Will post up some further code in about 8 hours when home.

Comment: Hi this is the IBAction code that I am using:

Comment: We cannot see the code, could you edit your question to add the relevant code ?

Comment: I'll have to put it up in a number of comments as it's saying its too long. I suspect the problem is that the geocoded function is executed on a remote server.

Comment: Geocoder is an asynchronous request made to Apple servers, that is why you have the completion block. Maybe you are trying to access your variables before its completion

Comment: @IBAction func btnInsertClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

        

  var locationRecord: LocationRecord = LocationRecord()

        

        // Get Address Information

        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

        let newLocation = CLLocation(latitude: valueLatitude, longitude: valueLongitude)

        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in

            if error != nil {

                println("Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            }

Comment: if placemarks.count > 0 {

                let placemark   = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark

                let addressDictionary = placemark.addressDictionary

                let address     = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressStreetKey] as! NSString

                let city        = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressCityKey] as! NSString

                let state       = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressStateKey] as! NSString

                let postcode    = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressZIPKey] as! NSString

Comment: let country     = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressCountryKey] as! NSString

                

                let universalVariableString = address

                NSLog("Address 1 kb  = %@",addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressStreetKey] as! NSString)

                NSLog("Address 1 var = %@",universalVariableString)

                

                println("\(address) \(city) \(state) \(postcode) \(country)") }

        })

        

        NSLog("Address 2 var = %@",universalVariableString)

   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely due to the fact that reverseGeocodeLocation is an asynchronous request made to Apple servers.

What needs to happen is:

1. You call reverseGeocodeLocation
2. reverseGeocodeLocation finishes, starts its completion which calls a method passing the placemark you just recovered.

In order to do that:

```
@IBAction func btnInsertClicked(sender: AnyObject) { 
    var locationRecord: LocationRecord = LocationRecord() 

    // Get Address Information 
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder() 
    let newLocation = CLLocation(latitude: valueLatitude, longitude: valueLongitude) 
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation, completionHandler:
        {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in 
            if error != nil { 
                println("Geocode failed with error: (error.localizedDescription)") 
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 { 
                let myPlacemark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark 

                // Here call the method that uses myPlacemark
                self.myAwesomeMethod(placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark)
            } else {
                println("No placemark")
            } 
        })
}
```

Where you need to use it in your code:

```
func myAwesomeMethod(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
    // Do stuff with placemark
}
```

I won't have my mac until tonight but if that doesn't work, leave a comment and we will work this out

Comment: That's it and very many thanks. Have wrapped the geocode component into its own func so a lot cleaner.

Comment: Seems to want: self.myAwesomeMethod(placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark)

Comment: Edited the code to reflect this. self must be used inside blocks ;-)